# Can't archive app after adding SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

We have an app with a lot of functionality. We have decided to move slowly to SwiftUI, and I've implemented one of the views as a SwiftUI view. We support older iOS versions (from 10.0), so I had to add a lot of `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` and `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` wherever needed around. The app runs fine on the simulators with different iOS versions. I can install it on my iPhone 11 with iOS 14, but when I try to archive the app I get a lot of errors, like:

- Cannot find 'UIHostingController' in scope
- Unknown attribute 'State'

and other stuff related to SwiftUI. It seems that it can't archive older versions.

I triple checked that all the classes and calls that relates to SwiftUI are tagged as only available for iOS 13. The application runs correctly on the iOS 12.4 simulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should install an iOS 10 simulator and build on that. That should help you see what is going wrong where

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew! With iOS 10.3.1 simulator (the oldest I could get) works fine, but still doesn't Archive. I changed the iOS Deployment Target to iOS 11 and now it archives. I'll talk to my team and see if we can move away from iOS 10.x.

Comment: No point going to 11, you should go to 12. There is no iOS device that has a max OS version of 11, that means if someone is on 11 they could upgrade to 12 to use the app.  https://iosref.com/ios

Comment: @Andrew Minimum OS version is never about device compatibility, but about users upgrading. There are many users in 11 that won't upgrade.

Comment: @Andrew I've seen many users stuck on old iOS versions because they've been out of storage space for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't properly solved the issue, but Change the iOS Deployment Target to iOS 11.0 fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out event @available(iOS 13.0) isn't enough for archiving SwiftUI code with deployment target < 11

Answer (score 1):

Changing the deployment target to iOS 11 as @Olav mentioned fixed it. However, digging a little deeper, it seems it's because **SwiftUI doesn't build for armv7** . Setting the minimum to iOS 11 excludes armv7 automatically.

This issue can be resolved by either:

1. Setting the minimum deployment target to iOS 11.0 as mentioned by @Olav
2. Manually limiting your project architecture to exclude armv7

   - project -> info -> architectures -> excluded architectures -> add `armv7`
   - will of course prevent your app from running on iPhone 5 / 5C, iPad 4th gen/retina
3. **Wrapping all SwiftUI code in the compiler directive: `#if !arch(arm)` / `#endif`**

   - `arch(arm)` matches armv7, `arch(arm64)` matches arm64 & arm64e